# Cannot plot polyline on D3 spinning globe

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a polyline path on a Mike Bostock spinning globe and animate a circle along it. So far I have learned how to do that along a polygon such as in the following example which has a circle travelling along Russia borders: http://jsfiddle.net/xqmevpjg/11/

Using the same code as in the fiddle above, I tried to add a polyline (e.g. a maritime route in Asia). My coordinates I plug in as follows:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"AsiaRoute"},"geometry":{"type":"polyline","coordinates":[[

[93.36182, 19.83325], 
[92.92236, 18.58833], 
[89.01123, 16.02932], 
[88.26416, 12.96642], 
[88.13232, 10.94591], 
[90.02197, 9.47548], 
[94.021, 9.43213], 
[94.72412, 12.2803], 
[97.36084, 12.62359], 
[97.49268, 11.42013], 
[96.70166, 9.17192], 
[96.43799, 6.99663], 
[98.41553, 5.86126], 
[99.38232, 4.54836], 
[100.12939, 3.23307]


]]},"id":"RML"},
```

This however does not work. The animation does not appear and the path is not even drawn on the globe. The only thing I can do is as follows :

(a) change the polyline to a Polygon, but then it connects the beginning to the end of the path and messes up the animation, or

(b) change geometry type to polygon once again, but this time "mirroring" the coordinates back to front so that I end up with a polygon which looks like a line. This doubles the amount of coordinates unnecessarily and then I am forced to divide my path length by 2 so that the animation stops 'half way'.

Is there a reason why I cannot simply plot the polyline as desired?? Help please :)

Comment: This fiddle you shared already has `AsiaRoute` in `collection`?

Comment: Hello Gerardo -thank you for your response. No, the fiddle does not as it is pointing to a public JSON (http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/world-countries.json).

Comment: Is this GeoJSON or TopoJSON? If it is GeoJSON, I can't find a polyline example in the specifications, check here: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples

Comment: Hello Gerardo. This is D3.

Comment: I know what is D3, thanks. I'm asking if the map is an GeoJSON or a TopoJSON. GeoJSON's don't have `polyline`. They have LineString and MultiLineString, though.

Comment: Sorry -I didn't mean it like that boss. I believe this map is a TopoJSON. I infer this from the tutorial here where Bostock uses TopoJSON (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)

Comment: No worries. I just checked, TopoJSON doesn't have `polyline` either: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson-specification/blob/master/README.md#22-geometry-objects

Comment: So are you saying solution (b) that I suggest is the only way to get this done?

Comment: Why don't you try `LineString` and `MultiLineString` first?

Comment: MultiLineString worked a charm, Gerardo. You, Sir, are a talented individual. Please suggest this as an answer and I shall accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be it a GeoJSON or a TopoJSON, these are the accepted values for the geometry:

- Point
- MultiPoint
- LineString
- MultiLineString
- Polygon
- MultiPolygon
- GeometryCollection

So, in your case, change `polyline` to `LineString` or `MultiLineString`.

Here is the specification for GeoJSON: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples

And for TopoJSON: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson-specification/blob/master/README.md#22-geometry-objects